# ARM GCC: Huge Char Array Does Compile Very Slowly Only

Tags: arrays, char, arm, ascii, long-integer

Using the ARM toolchain with the GNU MCU Eclipse compiling a very large **const char array** with over 12 KB, takes ages when compiling. The array is meant to be used for ASCII art.

Is there a way to speed this up?

**This is the compiler:**

*arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors 6-2017-q2-update) 6.3.1 20170620 (release) [ARM/embedded-6-branch revision 249437]
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.*

Comment: It's 2017. Is 12 *kilobytes* really "very large"? I wouldn't call anything "very large" if it could easily fit on a computer that's thirty years old.

Comment: In fact, what you might be looking for is a way to speed things up by using more space. i.e., a time vs. space trade-off. However, you should provide some code that shows what you are doing and what result you get, including some rough timings.

Comment: If the code is long, you can give a link to an off-site location for others to retrieve the array that gives the problem.  It is quite easy with a linker script to include a 'binary' and give labels to the start/end of the array for use with assembler or 'C'.  The binary will take little time to translate; an issue maybe with the build PC.

Comment: Can you be more specific: How long is `ages`, can you provide a MWE?